# How do I suppress git messages for files outside of my working folder in a large shared repo?

Tags: git

I cloned a work repo which has many files and folders, but my piece is just one folder and the files in it. When doing "status", it shows a series of deleted files in another folder somewhere that I can't fix by doing git checkout or git reset hard or anything else I could find. Maybe that's just something that's pending in the master? I have no idea.

Rather than F around and find out, I want git to pretend that only my folder exists. I know I could use `git ignore`, but that would change it for other people too. I want `git status` and every other command to ignore anything outside the folder, but without causing any changes to how the repo works for anyone else.

Comment: You could change your checkout to actually only contain your subfolder by using a [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) if you really don't need anything else (that won't help if you still need the other files present for some reasons, such as for a build).

Comment: You cannot use `.gitignore` for this (by which I don't mean "it would change it for other people too"—which isn't necessarily true, as there's `.git/info/exclude`—but rather this simply doesn't *work* as tracked files cannot be ignored). You *can* use `--skip-worktree` (which is the internal setting used by sparse checkout) for this, perhaps by using sparse checkout.

Comment: The most likely reason that some files are showing up as "deleted" in the "not staged for commit" section is that they literally *can't* be checked out for some reason, e.g., you're on Windows and someone has used case sensitive file names, file names like `aux` or `con`, or any one of the many other traps that Windows has.

Comment: Sparse checkout seems like the way to go! Can you post it as an answer? Regarding the "deleted", yes, I confirmed there's a permission issue of some kind and I'll be glad to sidestep it.